# Cant parse to date in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my jquery code i am able to get the value from datepicker

```
var to_date=$("#to_date").val();
var from_date=$("#from_date").val();
```

but i am not able perform the following

```
var startDate = Date.parse($("#to_date").val());
var endDate = Date.parse($("#from_date").val());
alert(endDate);// output nan
if(endDate<startDate){
  alert("invalid range");
}
```

can anyone tell me the reason?

**update**

```
html markup
  From Date: <input type="text" id="from_date" class="custom_date" name="from_date" value=""/>  
To Date: <input type="text" class="custom_date" id="to_date" name="to_date" value=""/>
```

Comment: Add your HTML markup also...

Comment: And the actual value you're trying to parse.

Comment: Please debug the code and tell us what is trying to parse...

Comment: @DaveNewton  from_date `22-07-2014` to_date `20-07-2014`

Comment: What do you mean by " i am not able perform the following"? What happens when you try?

Comment: You have to be careful when using a textbox to get a date. Entered as 2014-07-22 and 2017-07-20 the funciton works fine. You should use jQuery and the datepicker widget.

Comment: Okay when do get the dates? I mean when do assign values and call `Date.parse`? On click? You should be aware that on DOM load inputs are empty and so it will give you NAN...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the date object directly from `datepicker` instead of parsing it again from string

```
var to_date=$("#to_date").datepicker( "getDate" );
```

[**See getDate() Docs**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate)